# How can Entity Framework Code First Create Index in Descendent order?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

In fluent API, we can specify an Index on a field:

```
var indexAttr = new IndexAttribute("IX_EmployeeNumber")
{
    IsClustered = true
};

Property(c => c.EmployeeNumber)
    .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(indexAttr ))
    .HasMaxLength(8)
    .IsRequired();
```

After `Add-Migration`, we will get this `CreateIndex` statement:

```
CreateIndex("dbo.Employees", "EmployeeNumber", clustered: true, name: "IX_EmployeeNumber");
```

After a `Update-Database`, we have a sql like this:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_EmployeeNumber] ON [dbo].[Employees]
(
    [EmployeeNumber] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

My question is: how can I create this index in descendent order? Something like:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_EmployeeNumber] ON [dbo].[Employees]
(
    [EmployeeNumber] DESC
```

I couldn't find related parameters in `CreateIndex`. Is it possible to be achieved in Code First migration?

Of course we know we could get everything working with `DbMigration.Sql(...some sql statement...)`. But, how can we obtain the desired result with `CreateIndex()`?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at how to [customize code first migrations](http://romiller.com/2012/01/16/customizing-code-first-migrations-provider/) from the blog of Rowan Miller (one of the Entity Framework program managers).

This describes how to override the `SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator` sql generator to allow custom arguments to affect the generated sql.

As it happens, the scenario he walks through is extending the default behaviour of the `CreateIndex` migration operation to support specifying the creation of a **descending index**.

However, I don't think it is possible to expose this extension point to your code-first domain model creation code.

Answer (score 3):

**EF 7 Supports Index sort order!**

With EF 7 you can have multiple sorting orders on multiple columns.

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
        .HasIndex(b => new { b.Url, b.Rating })
        .IsDescending(false, true); //Added in EF 7.0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do what you were asking but also do it with multiple columns and multiple orders.

Based on [Matt Caton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25304675/771496) and Rowan Miller blog, I was able to answer my own question and get a custom solution that works as generic as possible (knowing that you cannot extend Entity Framework classes easily to add properties that don't exist).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29922099/how-to-add-an-index-on-multiple-columns-with-asc-desc-sort-using-the-fluent-api/31615040#31615040) for the exact solution.