# How to create ASC/DESC indexes in EF Fluent API?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, indexing, ef-fluent-api

In EF Fluent API we can create Indexes using

```
// In earlier versions
HasIndex(t => t.OccurrenceDate).IsUnique(false);
```

OR

```
// In older versions
Property(t => t.OccurrenceDate)
        .HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName,
                             new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_OccurrenceDate") {
                                     IsUnique = true,
                             }));
```

The question is how can I specify `ASC`/`DESC` attributes to created index?

Comment: "earlier" and "older" tend to be synonyms when talking about software versions. You may want to revisit the comments above each sample.

Comment: This might help you => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29922099/how-to-add-an-index-on-multiple-columns-with-asc-desc-sort-using-the-fluent-api

Comment: According to : https://github.com/jsakamoto/EntityFrameworkCore.IndexAttribute/issues/1 it's not possible via FluentApi. If you use db migrations you can add sql script that will create index for you.